# How to run NUnit test fixtures serially?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I have several suites of integration tests implemented in C#/NUNit. Each test suite is a separate class, each fixture setup creates and populates a SQL Server database from scripts. This all used to work just fine prior to Resharper 5.1.

Unfortunately, Resharper 5.1 begins to run several fixtures at the same time. This is a breaking change - they are all attempting to create and populate the same database, which obviously ends up in an mess. Is there any way I could have Resharper run my test fixtures serially?

If not, what would you suggest to run my NUnit test fixtures serially, one fixture at a time?
The order in which individual tests run does not matter.

Comment: Do you mean serially?  Sequentially implies that the order in which the test are run matters.  Serially just means that they are run one at a time, but the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Davy8: Yes, serially, I have corrected the question, thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know whether it is possible to prevent ReSharper from running tests in parallel; if not, the following hack might work: Create a static class with a static readonly `Monitor` member. Then, in `[TestFixtureSetUp]`, call `Enter()` on the monitor, and call `Exit()` on the monitor in `[TestFixtureTearDown]`. That way, only one test fixture will be allowed to run at a time. Not pretty, though...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about this ? I just tried this out.. by putting a trace of the following form in tests in 3 diff NUnit fixtures followed by a "Run all". Doesn't seem to be running in parallel.

```
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff") + "VC:Start");
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff") + "VC:Done");
```

Output I see is : (R# Build 5.1.1753.1)

```
01:06:41.6639IOC
01:06:41.6649Done - IOC

01:06:41.6679VC:Start
01:06:41.6729VC:Done

01:06:41.2439Mef
01:06:41.6589Mef-Done
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code being tested does its own transaction management, you can run each test inside a transaction. In that way, the different tests won't disturb each other. Also, you don't have to worry about cleaning up after each test, since the each test's transaction can simply abort after the test is completed.

In our projects, we usually let our integration tests derive from a class that looks more or less like this:

```
public class TransactionalTestFixture
{
    private TransactionScope TxScope;

    [SetUp]
    public void TransactionalTestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        TxScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                                       new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable});
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TransactionalTestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        TxScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work - these are test fixtures, not individual tests. Each creates a new database from scratch.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: Ah; I see now that I didn't read the first paragraph well enough.

Comment: What if you used `[TestFixtureSetUp]` and `[TestFixtureTeardown]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Give them alphabetical names, i.e. prefix them with a letter that signifies their running order. If you need this to happen you should be able to accept this nasty naming convention too.

Comment: Of course you could look at refactoring you tests to be able to run with their own instance of sqlite per fixture, which may take time but is a bit more honest.

Comment: Does Resharper guarantee that it will always run tests in alphabetical order? 4.1 did not do that - it ran them in top-to-bottom order. 5.1 orders them alphabetically.

Comment: @Alex: I tried it out yesterday and it runs my test fixtures one after the other in alphabetical order. We would always prefer not to rely on this to get the tests to work though as any test should stand alone or it is not really a unit. I couldn't find any setting to make tests run in parallel, but I don't have earlier versions.

Comment: Just reading through the other posts, I am intrigued by resharper running test fixtures in parallel. It doesn't happen on my machine, but a group of test fixtures in an assembly will all run serially if I click run tests on that assembly. If this is what is happening, then working with a TestFixtureTearDown would give you the chance to drop the database, and create it again in the next fixture. Sorry it's not much help, I can't reproduce the parallel fixture scenario.